# Проверка почты на Delphi

Tags: delphi, email

Собственно, как организовать?  Делал через IDpop3:

```
pop3.connect;
POP3.Retrieve(1,IdMessage1);
IDmessage1.SaveToFile('C:\temp.html');
Pop3.Disconnect;
```

Но в файл сохраняется полный заголовок сообщения (кому, от кого, через кого и тд), без самого тела сообщения.

Comment: в редакторе есть кнопка 101010 для подсветки кода, ну что вы мучаетесь))

Comment: нет такой кнопки О_о

Comment: А если найду?)))
101
010  - вот так она выглядит)

Comment: вы наверное подумали что есть волшебная кнопка в Delphi редакторе? xDDD

Comment: а сейчас уже все появилось, в смысле панель форматирования сообщений - раньше её не было О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pop3.connect;
POP3.Retrieve(1,IdMessage1);
p:=IDMEssage1.MessageParts.Count;
for i:=0 to p-1 do
begin
TidText(idMessage1.MessageParts.Items[i]).body.SaveToFile('C:\temp.txt');
end;
Pop3.Disconnect;
```